# O(logn) and algorithm relationship

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, big-o

I can't still get well about analyzing O(logn) algorithm

So if there is nested for loop where its inner loop increases/decreases by either one of multiplying or dividing, then it is Big-theta(logn) where its base is how much it is divided by or multiplied by?

**For example:**

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
for(int j=1; j<n; j*=5) ...

this is Big-theta(logn) with base 5 since it is multiplied by 5?
```

**Another example:**

```
for(int i=n;i>0;i--) {
for(int j=i; j>0; j/=10) ...

this is 
Big-theta(logn) with base 10 since it is divided by 10?
```

I mean, am I getting it correctly?

**Another question:**

Big-theta(logn) only work for nested loop only? (for loop inside the for loop)

Comment: In second example,Inner loop is infinite loop.

Comment: @SanketMakani Sorry, modified.

Comment: @Miku But the overall of complexity of the two above loops is Big-Theta(n*log(n)). It is only the inner loop whose complexity is Big-Theta(log n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can count how many times a particular `for` loop is executed then we can easily get an idea of the complexity. We can start with an example of a simple for loop.

Consider the following for loop,

```
for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
{
    //....
}
```

Now here if we want to find that how many times this `for` loop runs then we can do it by writing the series(as it is uniform series) and find that which term is `> m(limit)`. This way we can easily find number of iterations required by that `for` loop.

In this example, if we write all possible values of i,

```
1,2,3,4,5,......,m
```

This series is [Arithmetic Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). Now we have an equation for finding `n-th` term of the series as `{a(n) = a(1)+(n-1)*d}`. Here `d=1, a(1)=1` now we need to find maximum value n such that `a(n)<=m`.

We can do it by simply placing `a(n)=m` and find the value `n`. So here

```
m = 1+ (n-1)*1
m = 1+n-1
m = n
n = m.
```

So here total iterations would be `m` and therefore we can say that complexity of this for loop is `O(m)`.

Now consider an example you have given,

```
for(int j=1; j<n; j*=5)...
```

Here if you write all values of `j` then series would be `1,5,25,125,.....` and now this series is [Geometric Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). Formula for finding `n-th` term is `a(n) = a(1)*(r^(n-1))` and here `a(1)=1 and r=5`.

Now put `n(limit)`in place of `a(n)` to see how many times the loop executes and let us rename limit `n` as `m` to remove the confusion,

```
a(n) = a(1)*(r^(n-1))
m = 1*(5^(n-1))
m = 5^(n-1)
Now take log of base 5 on both side
log (m) = (n-1) //log is of base 5
n = log(m)+1
```

This way we can find here that total required iterations are `n = log(m)+1` where log is of base 5. After removing constant we can say that this loop has complexity of `O(log m)` with base 5.

Same way for the second example of you question, If you write the series of `j`, You will get `n,n/10,n/100,....` so it is also `Geometric Progression` with `a(1)=n , r= 1/10` and here `a(n)` would be `1` as we need to find that term.If you find total iterations, You will get it as `log n` with base 10.

> Big-theta(logn) only work for nested loop only? (for loop inside the for loop)

It is not necessary. Suppose we have only one loop which has the following format,

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i*=2)
```

This loop also has `O(log n)` complexity and it is not an inner loop. So this depends on the increment operation of your for loop. It defines the overall complexity of the for loop.